# Is it possible to query a custom field where the value is between two fields?

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have a custom post type with 2 ACF number fields: min_number and max_number.

In the post, say min_number is set to 100 and max_number is set to 1000 - is it possible to find this post based on a number that is between these two fields?

For example, if we search for 150, this is between 100 and 1000 so the post should be shown and if we search for 50 it shouldn't?

I hope that makes sense!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think it is pretty simple.
I got the reference from here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

```
$findNumber = 150;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'photos-videos',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'max_number',
            'value'     => $findNumber,
            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare'   => '>='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'min_number',
            'value'     => $findNumber,
            'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare'   => '<='
        )
    )
);

// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Make sense?

Comment: Almost... There is no `numberposts` param. It should be `posts_per_page` ;)

Comment: There *is* a numberposts param though...

Comment: @JacobPeattie Well, no - there is no such param in `WP_Query`. Such param exists only for `get_posts` function and if you take a look at its code, then you'll see, it is translated to `posts_per_page` when passing to `WP_Query` (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1689).

Comment: Sorry, you're right, had my wires crossed.